# How to get audio while using virtual display on GCP Linux machine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a VM machine with linux and I enabled virtual display on it.

After the setup, I was able to see the virtual display using chrome remote desktop but I don't know how to turn on audio so that I can listen to video that I opened on Google chrome in that VM instance using my local laptop speakers.

What commands can I run on the terminal to enable audio?